# netconf library installation error in robot framework

Tags: python, pip

I tried installing netconf library for robot framework and I got this error:

```
root@stack-ThinkCentre-M83:~/tests# pip install robotframework-ncclient

The directory '/home/stack/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. 
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. 
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The directory '/home/stack/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. 
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. 
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Collecting robotframework-ncclient
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/robotframework-ncclient/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework-ncclient (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for robotframework-ncclient
```

I tried the version check for robot framework and it returned the following

```
Robot Framework 2.8.4 (Python 2.7.12 on linux2)
```

What should I do?

Comment: why are you running as root? pip is complaining about that I think

Comment: oh good :) maybe you could add an answer explaining how you solved the problem :)